# How to add a spoiler without using shortcode-based plugins

Tags: formatting

I read it is advised not to use shortcode-based plugins, so I was wondering about an alternative elegant way to implement spoilers

Comment: what do you mean by spoilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with shortcode-based plugin if it's well made. To answer your question: there's probably hundreds of ways but this is probably the easiest and most performant (*similar to Reddit*):

- If you need to add a spoiler, go to **Text** tab in post edit page
- Add `<span class="spoiler"></span>` around the text you want to hide
- Add following `CSS` rule: `.spoiler { background: #000; }`. Has to be the same as text color or read the alternative below.

---

**Now you have two options:**

---

**1.** Show on hover: Add the following `CSS` rule:

```
.spoiler:hover { 
    background: transparent; 
}
```

---

**2.** Show on click: Add the following function to theme's `.js` file:

```
$('.spoiler').click( function() {

    this.addClass('show');
    // this.toggleClass('show'); <- if you want to toggle it for some reason
});
```

And the following `CSS` rule:

```
.spoiler.show { 
    background: transparent; 
}
```

If you want to show text *"Spoiler"* or something similar, you could use `CSS` `:before` or `:after`, position it and hide/show it accordingly using either `:hover` or class `.show` mentioned before.

---

**Alternative color:**

If you don't like dark spoiler boxes, you could modify this a little bit and also change text color to whatever color you chose for background. That way you could choose whatever color you want.

---

**References:**

[:before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp)**,** [:after](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp)

Comment: Good answer, though I disagree that shortcodes inside posts are a good idea (except when they're native to WP perhaps). Even if the plugin is well made, it creates dependencies all over your posts. If the plugin is discontinued you end up with a broken site.

Comment: You're right, I personally (_as a guy who generally knows what he's doing_) avoid plugins as much as I can, however sometimes it depends.. This for example is easy to code yourself and I would avoid plugins at any cost. But sometimes you just got to choose plugin.. I guess it depends, what client wants and how much is he/she willing to pay or if it's your own project - then you would probably do 99% yourself. But thanks for the comment @cjbj.

Comment: Nice one! I was wondering how to avoid an empty page if text is very long. If I've got it right, the text will be hidden, but the space on page will be actually used. I'll dig further to investigate a way to keep the page compact, expanding when needed